# How to make the flutter app responsive?

Tags: android, mobile, dart, flutter

I've been trying to make a flutter app (still learning) and I was able to make a login screen. However, I noticed that the app is not responsive. When I tested it on the emulator, it worked okay, but when I installed it to a phone with smaller display, I noticed that the widgets was not small, so the phone couldn't show the entire screen at once. Can someone help me with the making of this app responsive so it will fit with any size of screen?

My complete code is below;

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final TextEditingController _usernameController = new TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _passwordController = new TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    void printSomething(){
      print("Something was printed");
    }

    Widget buttonSection = new Container(
      padding: new EdgeInsets.all(32.0),
      child: new Row(
        children: [
          new Expanded(
            child: new Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                new MaterialButton(
                  child: new Text(
                    "Sign In", 
                    style: new TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 20.0
                      ),
                    ),
                  onPressed: (){printSomething();},
                  height: 50.0,
                  minWidth: 400.0,
                  color: Colors.blueAccent,
                ),

                SizedBox(height: 10.0),

                new MaterialButton(
                  child: new Text(
                    "Sign Up",
                    style: new TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 20.0
                      ),
                    ),
                  onPressed: null,
                  height: 50.0,
                  minWidth: 400.0,
                  color: Colors.blueAccent,
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );

    Widget textFieldSection = new Container(
      padding: new EdgeInsets.all(32.0),
      child: new Row(
        children: [
          new Expanded(
            child: new Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                new TextField(
                  autocorrect: false,
                  obscureText: false,
                  controller: _usernameController,
                  maxLines: 1,
                  decoration: new InputDecoration(
                    hintText: "Username",
                    icon: new Icon(Icons.person),
                  ),

                  style: new TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 20.0,
                    color: Colors.black
                  ),
                ),

                new SizedBox(height: 10.0),

                new TextField(
                  autocorrect: false,
                  obscureText: true,
                  controller: _passwordController,
                  maxLines: 1,
                  decoration: new InputDecoration(
                    hintText: "Password",
                    icon: new Icon(Icons.vpn_key),
                  ),

                  style: new TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 20.0,
                    color: Colors.black
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );

    Widget titleSection = new Container(
      padding: new EdgeInsets.all(32.0),
      child: new Row(
        children: [
          new Expanded(
            child: new Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                new Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8.0),
                  child: new Text(
                    "Please login using your credentials",
                    style: new TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );

    return new MaterialApp(
      title: "Service",
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),

      home: new Scaffold(
        body: new ListView(
          reverse: true,
          children: [
            SizedBox(height: 30.0),
            new Image.asset(
              'assets/logo.png',
              height: 200.0,
            ),
            titleSection,
            textFieldSection,
            buttonSection
          ].reversed.toList(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I wrote a simple solution based on a third party package here https://jaycoding.tech/tutorials/guides/how-to-create-a-responsive-app-in-flutte-xmafdg as I don't think MediaQuery is sufficient. You might want to check it out.

Answer (score 7):

i created  a detailed article about responsive UI in flutter and i hope it will help

- [Build Responsive UIs in Flutter](https://medium.com/flutter-community/build-responsive-uis-in-flutter-fd450bd59158)

TDLR(from the post):

1. In responsive UI we don’t use hard-coded values for dimension and
   positions. Use `MediaQuery` to get the real time size of the window.
2. Use `Flexible` and `Expanded` widgets to get a flexible UI that works
   with percentage rather than hard coded values.
3. Use `LayoutBuilder` to get the `ConstraintBox` of the parent widget.
4. You can get the orientation of the device using `MediaQuery` or
   `OrientationBuilder`.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks :)

Answer (score 6):

Best easiest way to make responsive UI for different screen size is [**Sizer**](https://pub.dev/packages/sizer) plugin.
[image: a busy cat]

Responsive UI in any screen size device also tablet. Check it this plugin ⬇️
https://pub.dev/packages/sizer

```
.h  - for widget height
.w  - for widget width
.sp - for font size
```

Use `.h`, `.w`, `.sp` after value like this ⬇️

Example:

```
Container(
  height: 10.0.h,  //10% of screen height
  width: 80.0.w,   //80% of screen width
  child: Text('Sizer', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0.sp)),
);
```

**I have build many responsive UI with this plugin.**

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

1. Avoid hard coded dimensions as much as you can.
2. If you cannot avoid fixing width or height to some value, try to calculate that value using actual screen size.
   *Example:* `MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - someValue`
3. Use properties available already instead of fixing width and height. Examples:

   **a.** crossAxisAlignment: `CrossAxisAlignment.stretch` for stretching your button to full screen size instead of `minWidth: 400.0`

   **b.** padding: `const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 12.0)`, for button vertical padding instead of `height: 50.0`.

Answer (score 1):

use orientation

```
double width, height;

if (MediaQuery.of(context).orientation == Orientation.landscape){
  width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.25; // width = 25% of the screen
  height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.25; //height = 25% of the screen 
}
else{
  width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.10; // width = 10% of the screen
  height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.10; //height = 10% of the screen 
}

child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: width),
       )

or

child: Container(
      width: width;
      height: height;
      ),
```